# Django Rest Framework error: {'user': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Unable to add a new customer to the database..
I made a class Named *customer* that has a one-to-one relationship with a class named *User* that is an AbstractUser

I want to send the data through rest API so that I can create a new customer in the customer table and a new user that is One To One Related to the customer from the same view.
**User Model**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
# Add additional fields here
id = None
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_homesampler = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_pathologist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
first_name = None
last_name = None
username = None

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'password']
objects = CustomUserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

# Ensure that the password is hashed before saving it to the database
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.password = make_password(self.password)
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_superuser
```

**User Serializer**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = get_user_model()
    # fields = (['id', 'username', 'email', 'name'])
    fields = '__all__'
```

**customer Model**

```
class customer(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(
    get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
real = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.name
```

**Customer Serializer**

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
userdata = UserSerializer(read_only=True, source='user')

class Meta:
    model = customer
    fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(**user_data)
        user.is_Patient = True
        customer = customer.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return customer
```

**Create Customer View**

```
# Create add customer API
@api_view(['POST'])
def addCustomer(request):

    customer_serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
    if(customer_serializer.is_valid()):
        customer_serializer.save()
    print(customer_serializer.errors)

    return Response({'message': 'okay'})
```

**Body of API Call**

```
{
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "password": "Abc"
}
```

So the question is how can I create a view so that I can create a new user and a customer using just one API Call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call body doesn't match `CustomerSerializer`.

`CustomerSerializer` fields are "user" and "rest", so you only can pass these two unless you do something like these:

```py
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userdata = UserSerializer(read_only=True, source='user')
    email = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = customer
        fields = ["userdata", "email", "password", "id", "real"]


    def create(self, validated_data):
        email = validated_data.pop("email")
        password = validated_data.pop("password")

        user = get_user_model().objects.create(**{
          "email": email,
          "password": password
        })
        user.is_Patient = True
        customer = customer.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        
        return customer
```

About the `create` method, it won't function correctly:

Because:

1. We shouldn't use `create` to create a new user instead we should use `create_user` [More](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user)
2. I noticed that you removed the username so this method would be useless :)
3. After `user.is_Patient = True`, you forgot to save the user

The correct code would be:

```py
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userdata = UserSerializer(read_only=True, source='user')
    email = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = customer
        fields = ["userdata", "email", "password", "id", "real"]


    def create(self, validated_data):
        email = validated_data.pop("email")
        password = validated_data.pop("password")

        user = get_user_model().objects.create(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_Patient = True
        user.save()

        customer = customer.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        
        return customer
```

NOTE 1:

```py
# Ensure that the password is hashed before saving it to the database
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.password = make_password(self.password)
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It is the wrong approach to make_password here because whenever you make a change in your user, it would run.

the ideal approach would be using `user.set_password("new_pass")` whenever you get a new password from the user.

NOTE 2:

When you pass `read_only` to a serializer, this means would be ignored if you passed it as `data` to the serializer.

About `write_only`, it's the opposite of `read_only`. It would not be returned if you called `serializer.data`. For example, we only want to write to the password, and we won't want to read it from the serializer, so we made it `write_only`.

### UPDATE: Adding a name

You have to add a write_only field and then pass it to `create` method

```py
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userdata = UserSerializer(read_only=True, source='user')
    email = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = customer
        fields = ["userdata", "email", "password", "id", "real", "name"]


    def create(self, validated_data):
        email = validated_data.pop("email")
        password = validated_data.pop("password")
        name = validated_data.pop("name")
        
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(email=email, name=name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_Patient = True
        user.save()

        customer = customer.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)

        return customer
```

Comment: Thanks, A LOT MAN! 
The thing is I started Django rest framework around 2 weeks ago and the documentation and other things are not that clear.

Tell me one more thing if I send the name in the call body, how can I store it in the user object at the time of creation? I tried getting the name from validated_data but it was not present in the validated_data object of the serializer but it was present in the request.data of the view.

Comment: @usamayaseen I updated the answer and added the name. if you want to add another field, just put them as write-only and then pass them to `create` method. I agree the docs are not clear, you have to test and read every single word on the doc.

Comment: So there was a problem with the create method for the user. It does create the user but only creates an object without any auth reference hence we cannot Log In. So, we need to use the auths "create_user" method so it will be  user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email=email, name=name)

Comment: and as the create_user requires email and password so the statement will be  : 
get_user_model().objects.create_user(email=email, password=password, "other fields")